# How to split items into columns (MVC3)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I cannot figure out **how to split items onto N columns.**
I.E. into 3 columns. How it could be done? (No I just did all things vertically)

Thank you for any clue!!!

```
foreach (var answer in @question.Answers)
{
   @Html.CheckBox("answer_CheckBox_" + answer.ID.ToString(), false, new { @id = answer.ID });  
   <label style="margin-left: 0.5em;">@answer.Title</label>
   <br />                                                                                                         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulus operator to separate answers into groups divisible by 3:

```
int i = 1; 
@foreach (var answer in @question.Answers) {
   @Html.CheckBox("answer_CheckBox_" + answer.ID.ToString(), false, new { @id = answer.ID });  
   <label style="margin-left: 0.5em;">@answer.Title</label>

   i % 3 == 0 ? <br/> : ""
   i++
}
```

*note - excuse my razor syntax if it isn't sound...*

Comment: Thank you @Xander !! You saved my time I appreciate your answer!