# n items show in 3 column logic

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, logic

I have n items.I want to show it in 3 column in View page.

```
@foreach (var x in ViewBag.list)
{
<tr><td>@x.Name</td></tr>
}
```

But I want to show it in 3 column.

```
<tr><td>@x.Name</td><td>@x.Name</td><td>@x.Name</td></tr>
```

Then what is the logic for this?Anyone helps me out.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198549/razor-view-dynamic-table-rows to see if that helps.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645419/how-to-split-items-into-columns-mvc3?

Comment: how to adopt this code for my situation.<div>
<table>
@for(int i = 0; i <= (Model.Count - 1) / 3; ++i) {
 <tr>
 for(int j = 0; j < 3 && i + j < Model.Count; ++j) {
  <td style="width:240px;margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px;">
   <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home", new { id = Model[i + j].drw_ID })" alt="drawing" /> 
  </td>
 }
 </tr>
}
</table>
</div>

Comment: I found this from Mike comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two for loops.  One for row and one for columns:

```
@for (var row = 0; row < ViewBag.list.Count(); row++)
{
    <tr>
        @for (var col = 0; (col + row * 3)< ViewBag.list.Count() && col < 3; col++)
        {
           <td>@ViewBag.list.ElementAt(row * 3 + col).Name</td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

And if you want to change the number of `td` elements per row, just replace `3` with a variable or hard code to a different number.

Comment: it gives me this error System.Collections.Generic.List<>' does not contain a definition for 'elementAt

Comment: my backend code  var pdlist = new List<Pollidut.Models.Pollidut>(500);
            pdlist = (from a in context.EMPLOYEES
                      join b in context.PERSONS on a.PERSON_ID equals b.PERSON_ID
                      where a.SUPERVISOR_ID == empId
                      select new Pollidut.Models.Pollidut
                      {
                          PollidutId = a.EMPLOYEE_ID,

                      }).ToList();
            ViewBag.PDList = pdlist;

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the method name.  It's this method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233(v=vs.100).aspx.  I'll correct the code.

Comment: Again {"'System.Collections.Generic.List<Pollidut.Models.Pollidut>' does not contain a definition for 'ElementAt'"}

Comment: You'll need to include a using statement for the `System.Linq`, or you can just you `@ViewBag.list[row*3 + col]` instead.   You didn't specify the type of `@ViewBag.list` which is why I used the `ElementAt` method as it works with Lists, Arrays and IEnumerables (if you include the using statement).

Answer (score 0):

Anyway this works for me.

```
  @{
            int count = 0;
            var tr = new HtmlString("<tr>");
            var trclose = new HtmlString("</tr>");
            <div class="panel-body noPad">
                <table class="table table-hover pdSbasic">
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (var pd in ViewBag.PDList)
                        {
                            <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" /></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" class="pdId" value="@pd.PollidutId" />@pd.PollidutName</td>
                            count++;

                            if (count % 3 == 0)
                            {
                                @tr;
                                @trclose; 
                            }
                        }
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        }
```